# bash adds extra single quotes

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I have a problem executing my script.
When executing it in debug mode (bash -x), I can see that bash is adding extra quotes. 
Therefor my script is failing.

Here this is within my script:

```
testvar="\"sudo /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 off\""
ssh -n -q -q -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 $1 ${testvar}
```

This is the output:

```
ssh -n -q -q -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 192.168.42.105 '"sudo' /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 'off"'
```

Answer (score 9):

Bash is displaying single quotes so as to show a command that is valid input syntax. It is not running a command which contains these single quotes in a parameter to the `ssh` command.

```
ssh … '"sudo' /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 'off"'
```

tells you that the last 4 parameters of the ssh command are `"sudo`, `/home/pi/shared/blink.sh`, `27` and `off"`.

On the remote host, the ssh daemon joins the words of the commands with spaces as separators, so the remote command that you are executing is

```
"sudo /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 off"
```

This attempts to execute a command whose name is `sudo /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 off`, which of course doesn't exist.

Remove the double quotes from your definition of `testvar`.

It doesn't matter here, but it probably matters in your real case: instead of `${testvar}`, write `"$testvar"` (or `"${testvar}"` if you want but the braces are optional). **Always put double quotes around variable substitutions** unless you know why you need to leave them out. `"$testvar"` expands to the value of the variable `testvar`, whereas `$testvar` when not in double quotes treats the value of `testvar` as a whitespace-separated list of glob patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Shell splits the value of the variable into words. Doublequote it to prevent the splitting. See the difference:

```
t='"a b c"'
set -xv
echo $t
echo "$t"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use:

```
testvar="sudo /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 off"
ssh -n -q -q -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 $1 "${testvar}"
```

This is working for me:

```
$ bash -x -c 'testvar="la la la"; echo "${testvar}"'
+ testvar='la la la'
+ echo 'la la la'
la la la
```

But if I write the same like you did, I get the same wrong result:

```
$ bash -x -c 'testvar="\"la la la\""; echo ${testvar}'
+ testvar='"la la la"'
+ echo '"la' la 'la"'
"la la la"
```

Comment: The quotes are crucial because they are the shell's mechanism to group several words together to form a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use function eval, this will resolve your issue

    testvar="\"sudo /home/pi/shared/blink.sh 27 off\""
    command=("ssh -n -q -q -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 $1 $testvar")
    
    response=$(eval "$command")
```